# How to properly output PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two blocks of code inside a .sql file. One block is a function and another is a procedure. In the first block, I'm running a query and printing it out to the screen (I'm using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() ) for each row in it's own line. Then the procedure has another query which needs to be printed on the same line (I'm using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT() ). When I use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT() for the second block, it screws up the first block for some reason and the first block never prints.

Here's a link to the code: http://pastebin.com/z29emmBJ
(The relevant part of the code is around lines: 97-103)

When I have DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() being used inside of the procedure, everything displays properly, but when I have DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT() inside of the procedure, it looks like the function never gets called.

Here's what the output looks like with PUT_LINE(): https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZgaQ.png
Here's what the output looks like with just PUT(): https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFgFV.png

I think it has something to do with the buffer size, but I'm not exactly sure what/why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to add `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();` after the loop? I mean after all the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT()` commands ?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just append the results to a VARCHAR2 variable as needed, then put_line that string when the row is completed?  That way you have control over the formatting.

Comment: That's a great idea. I feel silly for not thinking about that first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Snippet of the code of your Second stored procedure:

```
FOR player IN rows LOOP
   currentCount := maxCount;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(player.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || player.LASTNAME || ':' || player.points || ' ');
   --DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
END LOOP;
```

If you want that the resulting output appeared as a one line you should move  `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE()` outside the loop (after the loop). So your code would look like:

```
FOR player IN rows LOOP
  currentCount := maxCount;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(player.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || player.LASTNAME || ':' || player.points || ' ');         
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
```

Keeping `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();` inside the loop after `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT` you just emulating `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` procedure.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure output1
  2  is
  3    l_str varchar2(100);
  4    l_status number;
  5  begin
  6    for i in 1..7
  7    loop
  8      dbms_output.put('Text_' || To_char(i));
  9      dbms_output.new_line;
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created

SQL> 
SQL> create or replace procedure output2
  2  is
  3    l_str varchar2(100);
  4    l_status number;
  5  begin
  6    for i in 1..7
  7    loop
  8      dbms_output.put('Text_' || To_char(i));
  9     end loop;
 10     dbms_output.new_line;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created

SQL> exec output1;

Text_1
Text_2
Text_3
Text_4
Text_5
Text_6
Text_7

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> exec output2;

Text_1Text_2Text_3Text_4Text_5Text_6Text_7

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

---

In your code:

```
SET serveroutput ON size 32000;

REM Change output file name TO proj3-NetID.OUT!
SPOOL proj3-hgeorge3.OUT;
exec DBMS_OUTPUT.enable('100000000');
```

If `serveroutput` option is used (set to ON) then there is no need of calling  `DBMS_OUTPUT.enable` procedure. And if it happens to call `DBMS_OUTPUT.enable` then the value of numeric data type should be passed in as a parameter not a string. Yes there will be implicit conversion of data types but it's better to avoid it. And maximum size of the buffer is 1 million.

Comment: For the first part of your response:


I can't put it outside because the assignment wants us to build triangle basically, so it would look like:

row 1 (\n)


row 2, row 3 (\n)


row 4, row 5, row 6 (\n)

row 7, row 8, row 9, row 10 (\n)

row 11, row 12, row 13, row 14 (\n)

etc