# How to format my output in PL/SQL into straight columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am wondering how I can get my output of the following code to be displayed in a neat column.  The output now is not neatly organized. Is there something I need to put in front of my variable?

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Name: ' || (v_name));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job: ' || (v_job));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Pay: ' || TO_CHAR(v_pay, '$999G999G999D99'));
```

Comment: Not duplicate but related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004327/how-to-properly-output-pl-sql

Answer (score 4):

You're outputting a single string, so there is no opportunity for the values to be neatly aligned, as they could be in a simple select. The concatenation (`||`) just sticks together exactly what it is given.

All you need to do is manually pad the strings:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Name: ' || (v_name));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job:           ' || (v_job));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Pay:     ' || TRIM(TO_CHAR(v_pay, '$999G999G999D99')));
```

The `to_char` of the number column leaves it left-padded (right-aligned) to the width of the format mask:

```
SQL> select TO_CHAR(4.97,'$999G999G999D99') from dual;

TO_CHAR(4.97,'$9
----------------
           $4.97
```

... so in this case you want a `trim` around that so it only uses your own padding.

```
DECLARE
    v_name varchar2(30) := 'Joe Bloggs';
    v_job varchar2(20) := 'Contractor';
    v_pay number := 52657.3;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Name: ' || v_name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job:           ' || v_job);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Pay:     '
        || TRIM(TO_CHAR(v_pay, '$999G999G999D99')));
END;
/

Employee Name: Joe Bloggs
Job:           Contractor
Total Pay:     $52,657.30

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Display as columns - this is a simple way. You may employ Rpad(), Lpad() for this, which would be more advanced I guess:

```
DECLARE
   v_name varchar2(30) := 'Joe Bloggs';
   v_job varchar2(20) := 'Contractor';
   v_pay number := 52657.3;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Name'||chr(9)||chr(9)||chr(9)||'Job'||chr(9)||chr(9)||chr(9)||chr(9)||chr(9)||'Total Pay');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--------------------------------------------------------');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name||chr(9)||chr(9)||chr(9)||chr(9)||chr(9)||v_job||chr(9)||chr(9)||TRIM(TO_CHAR(v_pay, '$999G999G999D99')));
END;
/

Employee Name           Job                 Total Pay
--------------------------------------------------------
Joe Bloggs             Contractor           $52,657.30
```